# Pasar una variable de Javascript a CSS

Tags: javascript, css

Lo que quiero es pillar la altura total de la pagina y aplicarle un CSS dependiendo del resultado.

JS:

```
$altura = document.body.scrollHeight;
```

CSS:

```
#id{
height: $altura;
}
```

Algo así, como se debería hacer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La altura total de la página en CSS es `100vh` y el ancho es `100vw`

Actualmente no se pueden pasar variables de JS a CSS

**Solución:**

```
#id {
    height: 100vh;
}
```

Pd: Cuanto menos uses el JS, mejor para el WPO de tu web

Comment: Perfecto, gracias de nuevo!

Comment: Me la das por buena ? :(

Comment: _Actualmente no se pueden pasar variables de JS a CSS._  Eso no es del todo cierto. Puesto que puedes aplicar estilos CSS desde JS, entonces podemos decir que sí se pueden pasar variables de JS a CSS.

Comment: Soy consciente de que se pueden aplicar estilos en línea, pero aparte de que no son recomendables, no es lo que se pedía :(

Comment: Daniel resulta que no funciona del todo bien, si creo un nuevo dato via formulario y me hace un return a la pagina, no pilla el 100% del height con 100vh (recargo la pagina sin cache, y sigue sin pillar el 100%, sabes como solucionarlo? @DanielDíaz

Comment: Cómo ? No te entiendo .. :(

Answer (score 1):

Puedes aplicar el `css` desde Javascript. Por ejemplo, usando [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) (también es posible de otra forma en caso de incompatibilidad, ya que querySelector no es compatible con navegadores antiguos [ver especificaciones en el enlace]).

```js
//Usamos parseInt para quitar las letras como px
var paginaAltura = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector("body")).height);
console.log("Altura inicial body: " + paginaAltura);


var paginaAlturaNew = parseInt((paginaAltura + 100));
console.log("Nueva altura body: " + paginaAlturaNew);


document.querySelector('body').style.height = paginaAlturaNew + "px";

console.log("Altura final del body : " + window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector("body")).height);

// Con un div

var divAltura = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector("#test")).height);
console.log("Altura inicial div: " + divAltura);


var divAlturaNew = parseInt((divAltura + 100));
console.log("Nueva altura div: " + divAlturaNew);


document.querySelector('#test').style.height = divAlturaNew + "px";

console.log("Altura final del div : " + window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector("#test")).height);
```

```css
body {
  height: 100px;
}

#test {
  height: 10px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="test">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

De la manera que lo planteas no podria hacerse, pero puedes hacerlo asi:

**Considerando alto del documento**:

```
document.getElementById("id").style.height = document.documentElement.scrollHeight+"px"
```

**considerando alto del body**:

```
document.getElementById("id").style.height = document.body.scrollHeight+"px"
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar Jquery para facilitarte la vida. 
https://jquery.com/

Una vez cargado jquery puedes utilizar la sentencia:

```
$(function(){ 
   var windowHeight = $(window).height(); 
   console.log(windowHeight)
});
```

con esto podrás modificar a tu antojo las propiedades del la ventana como por ejemplo:

```
$(function(){
   $(document).css({ "background": "chartreuse" });
});
```

Comment: Acuedd, bienvenid@ a SOes. Tu respuesta es buena, pero el OP etiqueto su pregunta con "javascript". Si pudieras cambiar tu respuesta a Javascript seria muy bueno, en vez de sugerir algo que el OP no usa.